# Can't Access Custom Packages Method From another Package

Tags: java, oop, methods, package

I have 1 user defind package name `pack` and inside this pakage have class name `abc` and outside of this package i have another class name is `xyz`.

My File Hierarchy:

```
--> new (Folder Name)
    --> pack (Root Directory)
        * abc.class

    --> abc.java   (Outside of package)
    --> xyz.java   (Outside of package)
    --> xyz.class  (Outside of package)
```

abc file code

```
package pack;

public class abc{

    public abc(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public void sum(){
        System.out.println("hello i am method");
    }
}
```

xyz file code

```
import pack.abc;

public class xyz{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        abc obj = new abc();
    }
}
```

In this code when i create only Object (Means only call Constructor) in `xyz` file then i get output but when i call `sum()` method using object then i get error `Symbol not found`.

Following code for calling `sum()` method :

```
import pack.abc;

public class xyz{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        abc obj = new abc();
        obj.sum();
    }
}
```

Error :

```
error: cannot find symbol
        obj.sum();
           ^
  symbol:   method sum()
  location: variable obj of type abc
```

Comment: No , abc class should be in pack only

Comment: yes my `abc.class`  file is in the `pack`  folder ,but `abc.java`  file is outside of an `pack` folder. when i import `pack`  package in my `xyz.java`  file then i can't able to create abc class object then it's implemente the constructor and give output but When I try to call `sum()`  method using this object it Gives me error.